# How capture video thumbnail , when video is uploaded under media video type file?

Tags: 8, files, media

I'm using Core media module to upload video[Media Type is video,which has field video of 'file field type'].
This module will refer video.png as thumnail for all video uploaded from the local system.

I want to capture first frame of video as thumbnail when video is uploaded from the local system in media section.
I have seen '[PHP ffmpeg](https://www.drupal.org/project/php_ffmpeg)' , module , But i don't know the approach to follow to capture first frame of video.
 If i need to write a custom module to capture thumnail while saving media type of video, which hook function I need to use or please suggest me what apprach I can follow?

Comment: Same problem here. We need to figure out a way to capture a media thumbnail.

Comment: video embed urls field will create video thumbnails and store in file system. Uploaded video field, we need to find out.

Comment: Yes if you are talking about the module Video Embed it does create a thumbnail. But the core video field does not. As you mention it links to a generic video.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/media_thumbnails_video for this.

It has a dependency (`php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg`) that requires both the FFMpeg and FFProbe binaries to be installed on your server.